# Calculating average of elapsed time

Tags: grafana, influxdb, influxql, influxdb-2, influx-line-protocol

I want to calculate the average time duration of my events. After an event starts and ends, it sends a request to my InfluxDB in the [Line Protocol Syntax](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/cloud/reference/syntax/line-protocol/):

```
mes1 id=1,event="start" 1655885442
mes1 id=1,event="end" 1655885519
mes1 id=2,event="start" 1655885643
mes1 id=2,event="end" 1655885914
mes1 id=3,event="start" 1655886288
mes1 id=3,event="end" 1655886372
mes1 id=4,event="start" 1655889323
mes1 id=4,event="end" 1655889490
```

I can query the results like this:

```
from(bucket: "buck1") 
  |> range(start: -1w)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "mes1")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "event")
  |> elapsed()
```

Result:
[image: table]

As you can see, I also get the durations **between** those events, not only of the events themselves.

Consequently, when I add the mean() function, I get the mean of ALL elapsed seconds:

```
from(bucket: "buck1") 
  |> range(start: -1w)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "mes1")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "event")
  |> elapsed()
  |> mean(column: "elapsed")
```

Result:
[image: table]

How Can I get the average of only the events, not the time between them?

---

The durations of those events are:

- 77 sec
- 271 sec
- 84 sec
- 167 sec

So the expected result is 599/4 = **149.75 seconds**.

---

**Update:**

```
from(bucket: "buck1") 
  |> range(start: -1w)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "mes1")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "event"  or r["_field"] == "id")
  |> group(columns: ["id"])
  |> elapsed()
  |> group(columns: ["_measurement"])
  |> mean(column: "elapsed")
```

Result:

```
runtime error @6:8-6:17: elapsed: schema collision: cannot group string and float types together
```

Comment: Your example line protocol seems faulty: Here is what I had to use to successfully upload the data:
`mes1,id=1 event="start" 1655885442`
`mes1,id=1 event="end" 1655885519`
...
Changes are between commas and whitespaces. This could also explain why grouping by id does not work for you, as your screenshots do not show a column id.

Comment: After re-reading the Line Protocol docs I understand that your example line protocol makes id=1 a second field, while my version in the above comment makes it a tag. In my opinion a tag makes more sense, but I also do not know how two fields are treated in InfluxDB. In any case using a field key ("id") as a column is not possible in group().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to group by `id` and then ungroup via `_measurement`

```
|> group(columns: ["id"])
|> elapsed()
|> group(columns: ["_measurement"])
|> mean(column: "elapsed")
```

---

**Update**
I found another solution. Need to use `difference` instead of `elapsed`

```
|> filter(fn: (r) => r._field == "id")
|> group(columns: ["_value"])
|> difference(columns: ["_time"])
|> group()
|> mean(column: "_time")
```

Comment: Do I also need to add the field `id`? Please see my update. I'm getting an error now.

Comment: @gaout5 Try to filter only by `id`

Comment: In  this case I get the same result like before: `578.285714285714`

Comment: @gaout5 Hey! I updated my answer with another solution. I think it's a dirty way, but it works.

Comment: This time I get: `difference: difference does not support time columns. Try the elapsed function`

Comment: @gaout5 I used the same data as yours and that works https://pasteboard.co/wdZc9kyVrse9.png

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to filter after the calculation of elapsed?

```
from(bucket: "buck1") 
  |> range(start: -1w)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "mes1")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "event")
  |> elapsed()
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_value"] == "end")
  |> mean(column: "elapsed")
```

This seems to be the simplest way to get your result. Of course this assumes that you always have a sequence of start, end, start, ... As soon as this is not guaranteed, using id seems to be the more stable approach.